# Union of neighborhoods of measurable set is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable, show that
$$F=\bigcup_{x\in E}[x-1,x+1]$$
is also Lebesgue measurable.

My solution: the 'distance to E' function
$$\rho(x) = \inf\limits_{y\in E}|x-y|$$
is continuous and therefore measurable, hence $\rho^{-1}([0,1))$ is measurable. The remaining points in $F$ (those with $\rho(x) = 1$) form a set of measure zero, because they are isolated.

I am looking for alternative solutions and, of course, any corrections to my solution.

Comment: I don't see why the "remaining" points should be isolated. But the remaining points comprise precisely $(E+1)\cup(E-1)$...

Comment: Why did you have to pick $[0,1)$ instaed of $[0,1]$?

Comment: @user160738 I wondered about that. The answer is that $E$ is not closed, so there may be points in $\rho^{-1}([0,1])$ that are not points of $\bigcup_{x\in E}[x-1,x+1]$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $(E+1)\cup(E-1)$ may contain more than just the points with distance 1 to $E$.

Comment: @FrancisBegbie Hmm, true. But it's nonetheless true that $(E+1)\cup(E-1)$ _contains_ all the "remaining" points, so it does suffice to show his set is measurable.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich And to explain why the 'remaining points' are isolated, if 3 points of $F$ lie in a neighborhood of radius $1$, then at least one of them can't have distance 1 to $E$.

Comment: @FrancisBegbie True again. I'll shut up now...

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something, but can you not write
$E+[-1,1] = (E+\{-1\}) \cup (E + (-1,1)) \cup (E+\{+1\})$?

Since $E$ is measurable, so are $E+\{-1\}$, $E+\{+1\}$, and since
$(-1,1)$ is open, so is $E + (-1,1)$ (hence measurable).